# Plot Measurements Over Time [ggplot2]

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
   A1    A2    A3    A4    A5
   2     2     2     2     2
   3     3     3     3     4
   3     3     3     3     4
   1     1     2     2     1
   3     2     2     3     2
   4     4     4     3     4
```

I would like to plot multiple lines showing the trend from A1 to A5 (which are 5 measurements of the same variable over time) for each row (a patient) on a single graph using `ggplot2` in `r`, with the `y-axis` as a categorical variable with values `1 - 5`. I have gone through a lot of answers that suggest using `melt` from `reshape2` or `gather` from `tidyr`, but they do not quite produce what I want. Would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear on *how* you'd like to visualise your data but perhaps something like this?

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    rowid_to_column("patient") %>%
    mutate(patient = factor(patient)) %>%
    gather(key, val, -patient) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = key, y = val, colour = patient, group = patient)) +
    geom_line()
```

[image]

```
df %>%
    rowid_to_column("patient") %>%
    mutate(patient = factor(patient)) %>%
    gather(key, val, -patient) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = key, y = val, colour = patient, group = patient)) +
    geom_line() +
    facet_wrap(~ patient)
```

[image]

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "  A1    A2    A3    A4    A5
   2     2     2     2     2
   3     3     3     3     4
   3     3     3     3     4
   1     1     2     2     1
   3     2     2     3     2
   4     4     4     3     4", header = T)
```

To remove the x-axis you can do

```
df %>%
    rowid_to_column("patient") %>%
    mutate(patient = factor(patient)) %>%
    gather(key, val, -patient) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = key, y = val, colour = patient, group = patient)) +
    geom_line() +
    facet_wrap(~ patient) +
    theme(
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank())
```

[image]

Mind you, it might not be very sensible to remove the x axis.

Comment: Wow. Thanks a lot! The first graph is what I was looking for exactly! The second one looks much better and clearer, but I can't really use it because I have a sample of 30 patients! Basically, the idea is to compare the trend in the measurements for these patients to see if there's any general pattern. Any ideas?

Comment: @ayePete It's difficult to colour code curves for 30 different patients. Perhaps you have some other discerning features that would allow to cluster patients into subgroups? If so, you could group patients into clusters, and then visualise trends for different patients in different sub-groups. Alternatively, hierarchical clustering may provide insight into similarity across different patients, which you can then use to cluster patients into subgroups.

Comment: Thanks! Do you think it would be possible to cluster them by weight, BMI, or sex? If so, how would I do that? Pardon my ignorance, please!

Comment: BTW, I went ahead and did the 30 facet plots (lol), but now, I would like to hide the x axes, because they look quite unpresentable, given how many facet plots there are. How do I do that, please?

Comment: @ayePete (1) Different clustering methods exist, e.g. hierarchical clustering, k means, etc. Which one is most suitable depends on your data and domain-specific knowledge which I don't have. Take a look at some posts on SO and on the web to get an idea for how to implement such methods. (2) Nothing principally wrong with a 30 panel facet plot;-) provided data is shown in a sensible way. Take a look at some `ggplot` tutorials or google "remove x axis ggplot" to get some advice on how to tweak your (gg)plot.

Comment: @ayePete PS. I've updated my post to show how to remove the x axis.

Comment: Okay. Thanks a bunch for the help!